# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'", although it should be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, python-module, python-venv

when trying to run my Python script, I get the following error:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

I'm using a venv python environment. Before running the python script, I already activated the Virtual Environment (source myenv/bin/activate) and selected it in VS Studio Code as my Python Interpreter.

When I run "pip3 install lxml" to install to python module, I receive the following in the console:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable enter code here`Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /Users/XXXX/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (4.6.3)
```

When typing "python3" I get the following details:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Dec 21 2020, 15:06:04) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
```

I'm running macOS.

Comment: Your Python installation is a little screwy. You tried to install `lxml` into your Python3 environment but you can see it's being read from your Python 2.7 environment. If I were you I'd install anaconda, set up a conda environment, and make sure your IDE interacts with that environment.

Comment: @duhaime thanks for the reply! would it also be somehow possible to install the lxml onto my virtual env.? (python 2.7 should be the default environment, which is installed on every mac)
"pip3 install requests" installed the requests module without any issues on the virt. env., why is lxml making issues? would it maybe be possible to install it manually? thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try `python -m pip install lxml --user` to make sure that the Python you're using gets the module installed into its site-packages...